# Find a parametric equation that draws a quarter circle of radius 9 that crosses the y-axis and is as much in quadrant III as it is in quadrant IV.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles, parametric

In preparation for my precalculus test, I was assigned many challenge problems, including this one. I have been struggling to find a solution to this question, as when I graphed my solution, it seemed that the segment of the quarter circle in quadrant 3 was smaller than the segment in quadrant 4. Attached is a photo of my attempt.

I would really appreciate any help.

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBaw.jpg)

Comment: If you want someone to show you where you might’ve gone wrong instead of simply feeding you a solution (the latter is likely to get your question closed), include your own solution in the question.

Comment: Your  attempt is difficult to understand. I suggest you write your attempt in your question. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). By the way, why don't you just center the circle at origo?

Comment: Do you know how to find parametric equations for the circle with radius 1 and centered at $(0,0)$? Radius 3?